# Censoring emails in Java

Tags: java, strings

I'm working on a simple method that would censor emails (GPDR stuff) so they won't show the full name of a user, with 1st character, optional dot, 1st character after the dot and whatever is left after the @ to be left uncensored. So, the intent is like this:

Email to be censored: `name.lastname@email.com`

Desired effect: `n***.l*******@email.com`

I've written this:

```
public static String getCensoredUsername(String username) {
    if (username.contains("@")) {
        char[] chars = username.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 1; i < chars.length; i++) {
            boolean isCurrentCharacterADot = chars[i] == '.';
            boolean isPreviousCharacterADot = chars[i - 1] == '.';

            if (chars[i] == '@') {
                break;
            }
            if (chars[i] == '.') {
                chars[i] = '.';
            } else if (!isCurrentCharacterADot && !isPreviousCharacterADot) {
                chars[i] = '*';
            }
        }
        return String.valueOf(chars);
    }
    return username;
}
```

It feels to me very Java 6. What would make it look better?

Comment: Please take into account that here on Code Review answers won't come as quick as on [SO], hence you should really wait at least a day before you accept an answer althought it is mine ;-)

Comment: ok, noted. thank you for your help!

Comment: Feel free to unaccept my answer this could help to get more answers which may be better as well.

Comment: I get the feeling that you're hiding information but you want to retain some information in them so that the addresses can still be identified. This doesn't seem to comply with GDPR too well. If you want to protect privacy, just replace the shown e-mail addresses with an UUID and keep the e-mail -> UUID mapping in a protected database. As Fabio F. showed, your approach fails with common e-mail addresses leaving you vulnerable to GDPR violations so that too speaks against "e-mail address sanitation." (Instead of UUID you can use any shorter non-reversible and non-guessable random unique token.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a few remarks....

- if `username` doesn't contain a `@` the code should return early which saves one level of indentation.
- The condition `if (chars[i] == '.')` should better be `if (isCurrentCharacterADot)` but you could omit this as well because you won't need to assign anything to `chars[i]` if it is a dot.

This could look like so

```
public static String getCensoredUsername(String username) {
    if (!username.contains("@")) { return username; }

    char[] chars = username.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 1; i < chars.length; i++) {
        boolean isCurrentCharacterADot = chars[i] == '.';
        boolean isPreviousCharacterADot = chars[i - 1] == '.';

        if (chars[i] == '@') {
            break;
        }
        else if (!isCurrentCharacterADot && !isPreviousCharacterADot) {
            chars[i] = '*';
        }
    }
    return String.valueOf(chars);
}
```

As a side note, because this is a `public` method there should be some parameter-validation.

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing wrong about being "too Java 6"!

First few notes about naming and naming convention:

1. `username` is, in fact, the email, so should be `email`
2. `getCensoredUsername` for the same reason should be `getCensoredEmail` **but** in Java `get`, by convention, is used only for getter or when you're applying very little logic; thus is better to use an "action-subject" type of name like `censorEmail`
3. Being Java a type language, calling a variable `chars` is not helpful, that should be `emailChars` or even just `email` if that is not colliding with other variables, the compiler will tell you the type.

Biggest problem though, is the data validation, you should check at least that email is not `null`.

Normally you would check that the email is "valid" but if you take a look at the [email syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples) you might notice that's almost impossible to do it without writing a formal parser (or using some library). So let's say we want just censor the "reasonably valid" emails.

Your approach to go char by char in the username part is not very flexible: what if tomorrow you want to have `f****o.f*****i@gmail.com?` You need to add other flags, and wouldn't be very enjoyable.

I suggest you to start from the censor method and build bottom up from that.

Here is my solution

```
  public static String hideLastChars(String name) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(name, "String should not be null");
    if (name.length() <= 1) {
      return name;
    } else {
      return name.charAt(0) + IntStream.range(1, name.length()).mapToObj(i -> "*").collect(Collectors.joining());
    }
  }
```

Now that we have our "logic" we need to do a bit of input validation.

```
  public static String censorEmail(String email) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(email, "Email should not be null");
    String[] splitEmail = email.split("@");
    if (splitEmail.length > 1 && splitEmail[0].length() > 0) {
      return censorUsername(splitEmail[0]) + "@" + splitEmail[1];
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please provide a valid email");
  }
```

Now we know that the email is not null, it does contain a '@' and user is there.
We just need to apply our `hideLastChars` to each piece.

We have a little problem here because if you just split on each `.` you will end up losing trailing dots, for example in an email like `john.doe....@gmail.com`.
A solution is to use [Lookahead regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters) to split on each `.` but keeping it in the split result, this is the regexp: `((?<=\.)|(?=\.))`, for example `"john.doe...".split("((?<=\.)|(?=\.))")` will return `{ "john", ".", "doe", ".", ".", "." }`

Now we know how to map each piece and how to extract it.

```
  private static String censorUsername(String username) {
    return Arrays
        .stream(username.split("((?<=\\.)|(?=\\.))"))
        .map(scratch_1::hideLastChars)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
  }
```

I suggest you to create a unit test to test the logic so every time you find a new email that creates problem you can add in the test and see what happens (What about `p.g@curry.com`?).
I've run few examples using your code and mine. Here's the result

| INPUT | ORIGINAL | REVIEWED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `name.surname@gmail.com` | `n***.s******@gmail.com` | `n***.s******@gmail.com` |
| `name.surname.p99@gmail.com` | `n***.s******.p**@gmail.com` | `n***.s******.p**@gmail.com` |
| `name.surname.p99.@gmail.com` | `n***.s******.p**.@gmail.com` | `n***.s******.p**.@gmail.com` |
| `@gmail.com` | `@*****.c**` | `Exception: Please provide a valid email` |
| `user.com` | `user.com` | `Exception: Please provide a valid email` |
| `user%example.com@example.org` | `u***********.c**@example.org` | `u***********.c**@example.org` |
| `"john..doe..."@example.org` | `"****..d**..."@example.org` | `"****..d**..."@example.org` |
| `" "@example.org` | `"**@example.org` | `"**@example.org` |
| `null` | `Exception: Cannot invoke "String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)" because "username" is null` | `Exception: Email should not be null` |
| `...p...g...@gmail.com` | `...p...g...@gmail.com` | `...p...g...@gmail.com` |
| `p.g@curryfication.com` | `p.g@curryfication.com` | `p.g@curryfication.com` |

Comment: The "p.g@example.com" is a great example of how this approach is not going to work too well in practise. The sanitation scheme also leaves unique addresses fully exposed. I know people who own theirown domains and have "firstname@lastname.tld" addresses. Removing the first name does not make the address any less unique.

Answer (score 1):

If `username` is not an email, `getCensoredUsername(username)` does nothing, which is a little bit confusing.

Two possible approaches:

1. Call the method `censorLocalPart(String email)` and use it only if the username is an email. (this suggestion is on the lines of @Fabio F.'s review)
2. Add a comment (or Javadoc) to specify that a username will be censored only if it is an email.

An alternative is to use [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) with a regex:

```
public static String censorUsername(String username){
    return username.replaceAll("(?<=[^\\.])[^\\.](?=.*@)","*");
}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yVbaKH/1)

A brief explanation of the regex:

- `(?<=[^\.])`: lookbehind for a character that is not `.`
- `[^\.]`: match a character that is not `.`
- `(?=.*@)`: make sure that there is an `@` on the right. This is to exclude the domain of the email and usernames that are not emails.

Some tests (borrowed from @Fabio F.):

```
@Test
public void testCensorUsername() {
    assertEquals("simpleUsername", censorUsername("simpleUsername"));
    assertEquals("n***.s******@gmail.com", censorUsername("name.surname@gmail.com"));
    assertEquals("n***.s******.p**@gmail.com", censorUsername("name.surname.p99@gmail.com"));
    assertEquals("n***.s******.p**.@gmail.com", censorUsername("name.surname.p99.@gmail.com"));
    assertEquals("u***********.c**@example.org", censorUsername("user%example.com@example.org"));
    assertEquals("\"****..d**...\"@example.org", censorUsername("\"john..doe...\"@example.org"));
    assertEquals("p.g@test.com", censorUsername("p.g@test.com"));
}
```